# Cannot change NIS-password on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, password

My users are not able to change the NIS-password. I have also tried to change the passwords as root on the NIS-server, but without success. When I try to change the password by running yppasswd on the server I get the message "Error while changing the NIS password".

rpc.yppasswdd is running on the server.

How can I troubleshoot this?